# How do I run assets:precompile with Rails in a subdirectory on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have a rails app in a subdirectory, published to heroku.

```
Gemfile
Gemfile.lock
Rakefile
config.ru
railshost/
  app/
  etc...
```

- If I run it (locally) from the base Rakefile, `assets:precompile:nondigest` fails with (nil should be the sprockets environment)

  ```
  undefined method 'each_logical_path' for nil:NilClass
  .../gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
  ```
- If I extend `assets:precompile` to cd to `railshost` and then run the task, it fails on Heroku because `bin/node` can't be found - it appears to be a relative path.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm having a similar error, but it seems to be triggered by something different. I'm wondering if the solution might be similar.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm picking pieces out of an application that has some other things going on, so hopefully this all works)

### `Rakefile`

The precompile calls some subtasks.  We have to trick it into shelling out to maintain our hacks.

```
ENV['RAILS_GROUPS'] = nil # trick asset rake file into shelling out
```

Rake has to run in the rails directory

```
task :railshost do
  cd 'railshost'
end

# this gets called by heroku
namespace :assets do
  task :precompile => [:railshost]

  namespace :precompile do
    task :nondigest => [:railshost]
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, this breaks Heroku's node path

### `railshost/bin/node`

```
#!/bin/sh
../bin/node $*
```

And of course all the usual applies - set application to compile assets, serve assets, and so on.